# How can I get italic fonts in byobu

Tags: byobu

I'm following the guide here: https://alexpearce.me/2014/05/italics-in-iterm2-vim-tmux/

and it works for default tmux, but if I start tmux via byobu, the term type is `screen-256color`. It seems `~/.tmux.conf` is not getting sourced.

I tried adding the same `set -g default-terminal "tmux"` to `~/.byobu/window.tmux` but that prevented byobu from starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried again today and I found that byobu reads .tmux.conf from ~/.byobu or maybe it is ~/.local/share/byobu/. I symlinked that to my ~/.tmux.conf and I now have italic fonts. I rarely use tmux directly. I guess I could have copied it.

Summary:

```
# Paste this in a terminal.
cat <<EOF|tic -x -
tmux|tmux terminal multiplexer,
  ritm=\E[23m, rmso=\E[27m, sitm=\E[3m, smso=\E[7m, Ms@,
  use=xterm+tmux, use=screen,

tmux-256color|tmux with 256 colors,
  use=xterm+256setaf, use=tmux,
EOF
echo 'set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"' >> ~/.local/share/byobu/.tmux.conf
```

Restart byobu and test that it works:

```
# I have italics
echo `tput sitm`italics`tput ritm`
# I have 256 colors
```

Comment: Great resource, thanks. I didn't realize how bad things were until I fixed them ;-)